# Partitioning method that can help to avoid having to specify the same information or column in Hive Partitioned Query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, data-analysis, data-science

I have daily transactions with up to 5-10 GB of data per day. In my view it makes more sense to partition by month..

Here is an example:

**My Table has the following columns:**

TRANSACTION_DATE TIMESTAMP -- transaction date

TRANSACTION_AMOUNT INTEGER - transaction amount

DWH_PARTITION STRING -- technical field that goes into PARTITIONED BY section

Now I want to query for the amount of transactions between January 15st 2015 and November 15th 2015.

My query would be

```
select sum(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) from TEST where TRANSACTION_DATE >= CAST('2015-01-15' as timestamp) AND TRANSACTION_DATE < CAST('2015-11-15' as timestamp)
```

This query returns correct data but it does full table scan while I would like it to just use partitions 2015-01, 2015-02, .... 2015-11.

To do so I need to specify manually which partitions should I use so the query would be as follows:

```
select sum(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) from TEST where TRANSACTION_DATE >= CAST('2015-01-15' as timestamp) AND TRANSACTION_DATE < CAST('2015-11-15' as timestamp) and DWH_PARTITION in ('2015-01',.........'2015-11');
```

Because we cannot partition by timestamp business analyst would have to know the exact partitioning pattern (whether given table is partitioned by month, day, etc.).

Please also note that information about dates need to be specified two times: one for transaction date and then for partitions.

**Do you know some partitioning methods that can help to avoid having to specify the same information twice and release the user from having to know partitioning patters of all the tables they need to query?**

Comment: **Do you know if any other database has such a feature** e.g. guess what a user wants without him typing any SQL? Ask IBM, maybe their Watson thing can do it.

Comment: You did not bother to explain what table format you are using. Try ORC with Gzip compression, it will help with the full scan (i.e. scan stripe headers to check TRANSACTION_DATE min/max and skip the stripe if it does not match the WHERE clause).

Answer (score 0):

It can be only achieved by range partitioning and currently it is not supported. Probably UDF might help, but 100% not sure.

We have solved that problem by providing simple web interface where user can choose the table, filter columns and under the covers application is intelligent enough to generate the query leveraging partition pruning.